# EF Core Populate a "NotMapped property" from a not included List of entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities like these

```
    public class PetShop
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IList<Cat> Cats { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Cat OldestCat {
            get => Cats.OrderBy(c => c.BirthDate).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public class Cat
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Normally to get the PetShop with all the cats, this is the query I have to make with my DbContext:

```
    DbContext
        .PetShop
        .Include(a => a.Cats);
```

But sometimes I do not want to include all the cats of my PetShops, since I could have a lot of cats, but I still need to populate my OldestCat, but without including the cats, my getter will return me nothing.

Is there a way to populate my NotMapped OldestCat property without including all my cats ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit. I changed the answer. Mabye the easiest would be to make a link from cat to petshop and then begin with the Cat and from that Select the petshop?

I have not tested the code.

```
DbContext
.Cats
.Where(c => c.PetShop.Id == 5)
.OrderBy(c => c.BirthDate)
.Select(c => c.PetShop)
.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I don't understand your point: the OldestCat property is on the PetShop class, since I want this to be always available.

Comment: @ChrisK yeah sorry, i can see that didn't work so I gave another try.